# Question on flip-flops

Tags: clock, flipflop, memory, latch

I came across a question which says the following,i don't understand the question and how to come up with a solution

**In fig,the data word to be stored is S=1001**

**a)If LOAD is LOW,what does Q equal after the positive clock edge?**

**a)If LOAD is HIGH,what does Q equal after the positive clock edge?**

[image]

It'd be really helpful if someone explains the solution,I got the basic knowledge about flip-flops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LOAD signal here functions as a *Synchronous Active-Low Reset*. As long as LOAD is 0, the flops will get loaded with 0 on clock's positive edges. When LOAD is high, whatever value that's present on {S3 S2 S1 S0} will get loaded into the flops on positive clock edges.

Answer (score 0):

As the flip-flops are gated with AND-gates, when LOAD is low, 0 will be fed into the FF. When LOAD is high, the word 1001 is fed into the FF.